# LPC11xx Cortex-M0 FreeRTOS Hardfault

Tags: arm, memset

I have been working with a project on an NXP LPC11XX device and FreeRTOS.  The issue is that the demo project for this uses some Eclipse based IDE and I wont have any of that.  I got it converted to compile in linux and I can program without any issue.  The problem I am seeing is when the demo project gets to a memset() a hard fault is generated in the CPU.  This is not my code, but I have a feeling it is related to something that I did.  I am using the codesourcery "gcc version 4.4.1 (Sourcery G++ Lite 2010q1-188)" compiler (which I have used without issue on Cortex-M3 devices).  I see the hardfault generated on a damn "lsls" instruction which touches nothing in memory, see this massive pastebin of GDB output: http://pastebin.com/3pg0puSe (I don't know what common practice is here for large blocks of text like that.)

Any thoughts, anyone?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why not use the official FreeRTOS support forums?

Comment: This seems like a more in-depth ARM issue, somewhere between memset(), gcc, and possibly my makefile.  This has nothing to do with the freeRTOS kernel as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard to see, but the last instruction was `blx     r3`.
It looks like R3 did not have its last bit set (for Thumb mode), its value is `0x481c`. 
This will IIRC cause an illegal instruction exception. Your debugger fools you in this case, as the value loaded into the PC by `blx` was probably invalid.

You might just forgot the linker option which sets the instruction mode/CPU model (and the set of libs to use) - so it linked against an ARM mode library.

Comment: The compiler is definitely specifying -mthumb, but you are very much right, I did not catch that missing bit.  When I get home later I will check that out.  Thanks for the input!